# Inserting file content into MySQL database via FormBuilder in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2 app I have a need to provide an option to upload a text file. I've already achieved this by using the FormBuilderInterface to create a field with the 'file' type. The file gets uploaded properly but all I really need is to fetch the text from the file and insert it into the proper db table column. Is there a way to fetch the text from an uploaded file on POST? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways.

- Using [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)
- Using [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

In both cases the main point is to open uploaded and fill its content to the entity property (after form posted but before data persisted to db). So you need to have 2 entity properties for this: uploaded file handler (not mapped to the db) and file text itself (mapped to the db).

Here is an example with the lifecycle callbacks:

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class SomeEntity {

    /**
     * Virtual field used for handling the file
     *
     * @Assert\File()
     */
    private $fileHandler;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function saveFileContent()
    {
        $tmpName = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' . $this->fileHandler->guessExtension();
        try
        {
            $this->fileHandler->move(
                '../../../tmp/',
                $tmpName
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}

        $this->setFile(file_get_contents('../../../tmp/' . $tmpName));
        unlink('../../../tmp/' . $tmpName);
    }
}
```

This also might be helpfull: **[How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)**